# Wordpress pages theme/layout

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'd like to know whether I could have different layout and content for each page?
For example, I have 4 pages, and I have 4 completely different layout design, do I need to make 4 themes then apply to different pages or something else?

Moreover,   can I have different posts show on different page?
like post no.1/or tag [google] goes to page 1, post no.5/tag[orange] goes to page 3?

I'd like to learn how to structure this idea.
Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the diffrent template for different pages  to show the  different  design on  every page

for  making template   create normal php file  and at the top of file  add the  code for every template  by replacing template  name

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:About Us

 */


  ?>
```

By this  you get different template  for about us  put you code desing that  you want to show for  this page  and from that  back end select the  template  from rignt hand side option and save  that page .

And to show different post on different pages  you need to create category after that  where you want to call the post for page call the  category   code for  that

```
<?php Query_post('cat=3&showposts');
      while(have_posts()): the_post();
           the_title();
       endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?> every time  on different page you just chage the category id   (cat)
```