# Determine layouts per page for Wordpress Themes

Tags: wordpress, layout, widget, wordpress-theming

I would like to determine differenent page layouts for pages within Wordpress. As stated in the thread [Wordpress pages theme/layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513375/wordpress-pages-theme-layout)
it is uggested to use templates. But for customer convenience, I would like to have a layout on the WP admin page where I would have different pages (instead of widget areas) where I could drag and drop widgets in.

I know there are some plugins which offer the possiblity to determine which widgets are shown in which pages (plugin: Display Widgets), but as we intend to have a lot of pages this solution would end up showing widget areas with too much widgets in it. 
So it would be great to have pages and widget areas in them, to drag and drop widgets in there.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I would like to explain more precisely what I would like to achieve:

- different named layouts to hold different compositions of widget areas (set of header, sidebars, footers)
- pages (not posts) can choose from those layouts to determine their structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider a plugin such as Visual Composer for something user friendly. You can add sidebars into layouts by dragging and dropping. Check it out here: [Visual Composer](http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Visual Composer looks like a capable plugin or framework, but it is overweighted somehow. I cannot see if it is possible to have different widget layouts per page.

Comment: You create the page layout with VC in the visual editor and then drag and drop the widget where ever you need it.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you. VC is not free of charge and I would have to use it at office where I work so some costs apply. It is quiet expensive if we would sell our theme composed with VC.

Comment: I think VC is quiet confusing and needs time to understand it und use its full power, nevertheless it is an impressive plugin. Altough I will use other plugins and try to avoid to use it, I cannot say I long I can refuse using it ;-) So I give you the "answered" flag :-)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the perfect solution for my problem.

To use or determine different layouts (grid of widget areas) per page, I found the plugin WP Page Widget, please see here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-page-widget/.
It is free to use and adds perfect customisation possibilities to my site.